# Opera redirect problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi everyone i have a problem like this.

For example im in http://localhost/Search.aspx
I have 2 textboxes (txtUserName and txtPassword) in my page for login. 
user can press enter key to call Login() method when any of these textboxes focused.
I capture enter key like this

```
txtUserName.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {Login();return false;}} else {return true}; ");
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {Login();return false;}} else {return true}; ");
```

Its calling the Login() method, and After doing that method Opera redirects the page to my default page (http://localhost/Default.aspx)

Other browsers is working as it should, in other words they are not redirect me to the default page.

Opera version 10.61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you're problem here is Opera (bless it) doesn't support the `onKeyDown` command very well - so you have to look at `onKeyUp` or `onKeyPress` instead.  There's a really handy HTML table on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t09) explaining this.

Given you're only trying to trap a control key `onKeyUp` is probably your best bet.  I've been forced to combine `onKeyDown` and `onKeyPress` in order to catch text input AND control keys (but since you want text input to work as normal you don't need to go this far).

It should be simply a matter of switching "onkeydown" to "onkeyup" in your example fragment.

There is, perhaps, a question of why you'd be doing the above.  I don't know what `Login()` does, but building a form with 3 parts (input-text, input-password, and input-submit button) will -by default- submit the form when enter is pressed in either of the input boxes, you could just add an `onSubmit` event to the form calling `Login();`